# Reuse code in multiple settings.gradle

Tags: groovy, gradle

I have several multi-project builds that have a lot of common code in settings.gradle. How can I factor this code out to a separate file?

I have tried to use GroovyShell, but I cannot see how to configure the bindings so that method calls go into the surrounding Settings class.

Comment: What kind of things is the common code doing?

Comment: Including the same sub-projects for a common project that is merged into several other projects. In any case, I have solved this in the meantime with `apply: from file(...)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the meantime, I found out that you can call

```
apply from: file('otherFile')
```

in settings.gradle, just like in projects. My problem is solved with that.

Answer (score 0):

Do one of the following:

- Specify gradle file on the command line. The command line option is -I or --init-script followed by the path to the script. The command line option can appear more than once, each time adding another init script.
- Put a file called init.gradle in the USER_HOME/.gradle/ directory.
- Put a file that ends with .gradle in the USER_HOME/.gradle/init.d/ directory.
- Put a file that ends with .gradle in the GRADLE_HOME/init.d/ directory, in the Gradle distribution.

More information is here: http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/init_scripts.html

Comment: I don't think that init scripts can be applied to settings.gradle.